# Sencha Touch 2.1.1 and Google Maps Error on packaged web app only

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch-2.1

When I run the unpackaged version of the web app I don't have any problems. The map centers just fine and displays properly. However, whenever I package the app I get two issues. First when it launches I get the following warning:

```
Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

The only place that I load the API is in the app.json file.

Then when I go to the part of the app with the map I got the following Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <center>: (39.810166, -86.15670799999998)
```

Why would this work fine pre-packaged, but not post-packaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up getting a response on the Sencha forums when I pushed it to the bugs forum. Apparently it works better if you load the google maps api in the index.html instead of the app.json file. Once I did that it worked just fine. You can see the thread there here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261932-2.1.1-Packaged-web-app-won-t-load-google-map-with-initial-center-point